# Java: How would I declare an undefined number of object with user inputted data?

Tags: java, object

for my assignment I am suppose to have a user input the name and price of items. However, they are to enter in an unlimited amount of times until a sentinel value is used. I don't actually know how I'd go about doing this. The only way I know how to declare an object with user input is to use a scanner and then place that data within the arguments of a constructor. But that would only create a single object. Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Item

{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



} 

private String name;
private double price;

public static final double TOLERANCE = 0.0000001;

public Item(String name,double price)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
}

public Item()
{
    this("",0.0);
}

public Item(Item other)
{
    this.name = other.name;
    this.price = other.price;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void setPrice(double price)
{
    this.price = price;
}

public void input(String n, double item)
{

}

public void show()
{
    // Code to be written by student
}

public String toString()
{
    return "Item: " + name + " Price: " + price;
}

public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if(other == null)
        return false;
    else if(getClass() != other.getClass())
        return false;
    else
    {
        Item otherItem = (Item)other;
        return(name.equals(otherItem.name)
            && equivalent(price, otherItem.price));
    }

}

private static boolean equivalent(double a, double b)
{
    return ( Math.abs(a - b) <= TOLERANCE );
}
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about Lists or arrays yet?

Comment: Not lists but I did learn about arrays,

Comment: Well, an array can be used here, with some 'limits' on how many items can be created. Create an array sized for 1000 elements (ie. not super huge, but more than the user will ever enter). And then also keep a howManyItemsHaveBeenAdded variable. When you ask for using input (using a `while` or `do-while` loop, probably), create the object from the input and then assign it to the appropriate array element (at the end of the previously added items) and increase the counter variable. (If Lists are allowed the adding could be simplified..)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you want just initialize an array of obects.

Firstly you need initialize an array:

```
int n = scanner.nextInt();  // you may get n in other way 
Item[] items = new items[n];
```

Then you can fill it with new instances of Item:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    items[i] = new Item(); //constructor args may be here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add undefined number of object best choice is `List` in java. By using your example i add some code in `main()` method as below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.print("Enter item name :: ");
            String name = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter item price :: ");
            while (!input.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.err.println("Invalid Price (Double) eg. 300");
                System.out.print("Enter item price :: ");
                input.next();
            }
            double price = input.nextDouble();
            Item item = new Item(name, price); //creating object by passing value in constructor
            items.add(item); //adding object in list
            System.out.println("Do you want to add more items ? 'Y'=>Yes or 'N'=>No ");
            String ans = input.next();
            if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(ans)) {
                break;
            }

        }
        //To retrive item object list
        for (Item i : items) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
```